# SQL convert array column to rows with old keys in arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL, with two columns: `id` and `nodes`. `id` is of type `bigint`, as it is the primary key in the table. `nodes` is an array of `bigint`. I would like to create a new table, where the nodes in the `node` arrays are the keys and the only other column is an array of `ids` that correspond to that `node`.

So let's say the original table is like this:

```
id | nodes
1  | {200, 300, 400}
2  | {200, 300, 400}
```

then the new table should be like:

```
node | ids
200  | {1, 2}
300  | {1, 2}
400  | {1, 2}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f8ec8f87ed20e3c07c160fae2ff27424)

```
SELECT node, array_agg(id) as ids
FROM (
    SELECT id, unnest(nodes) as node 
    FROM nodes
)s 
GROUP BY node
ORDER BY node
```

`unnest()` expands the array into one row per element.

Then you are able to `GROUP` by the array elements and aggregate the `ids` with `array_agg`

---

In your case this can be shortened to a query without any subquery or join:

```
SELECT unnest(nodes) as node, array_agg(id) as ids 
FROM nodes
GROUP BY node
ORDER BY node
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unnest and re-aggregate.  No subquery is necessary:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as id, array[200, 300, 400] as nodes union all
      select 2 as id, array[200, 300, 400] as nodes 
     )
select node, array_agg(t.id)
from t cross join
     unnest(nodes) node
group by node
```